# Schoenfeld residuals and Categorical variables with multiple categories

Tags: r, survival, schoenfeld-residuals

I am having a bit of trouble with my survival data.
Basically I am trying to assess whether or not the cox proportional hazard assumption is met, by ploting the schoenfeld residuals in R.

I have several variables and some of them have 3 or more categories.
As far as I know, Schoenfeld residuals are adjusted for each individual and each variable. So, when I tried to get the residuals for each of this variables with 3 or more categories, I was expecting to have one residual for individual, but instead I got more.

It's my first time using R with survival data, so probably I am doing something wrong. Here is the code I used with a variable that has 4 categories.

```
>fit=survfit(s~data$school)

#Cox Model
>summary(coxph(s~data$school))

#Test for proportional hazards assumption
>cox.zph(coxph(s~data$school))

#Schoenfeld residuals (defined for each variable for uncensored subjects)
>res=residuals(coxph(s~data$school), type="schoenfeld", collapse=F)
```

When I call the first 3 rows (time = 7 days), I get a set of 3 residuals per individual:

```
> res[1:3,]

       data$school2     data$school3     data$school4
7        -0.6250424       -0.1333578        0.8462863
7        -0.6250424       -0.1333578        0.8462863
7         0.3749576       -0.1333578       -0.1537137
```

Can anyone please help me we this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate Schoenfeld residual *for each covariate* for every uncensored individual.

In the case of a categorical covariate with $k$ levels, $k-1$ dummy variates appear in the model.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.
In this case, my covariate is school, it has 4 levels or categories. Each uncensored individual has a number from 1 to 4, that corresponds to the respective category of the covariate school.

I was expecting to get only one residual for each of this uncensored individuals, because I only have one covariate (school), and if I understood correctly, what you answered is what I was expecting. But the R code gave me 3 distint residuals for each individual.

Comment: There are three dummies in the model for a four-level categorical covariate. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally it is a good idea to concentrate the effects of a categorical predictor just for the purpose of checking proportional hazards or interaction.  If you don't want 3 d.f. for the PH test you can use `predict(fit, type='terms')` to get one column for each predictor, then run `cox.cph`.  This doesn't exactly preserve type I error but it's close.  The method doesn't recognize that 3 parameters are being estimated instead of 1.